Psalm laravel UndefinedMagicMethod
Psalm speaks of mistakes...
UndefinedMagicMethod  Magic method App\Models\User::wherenull() does not exist
UndefinedMagicMethod  Magic method App\Models\User::create()
UndefinedMagicMethod  Magic method App\Models\User::get()

The following packages are installed

"vimeo/psalm": "^5.24"
"psalm/plugin-laravel": "^2.11",
barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^v3.0",

Command exucutes:

php artisan ide-helper:models
php artisan ide-helper:generate

How to fix ?

Check that the laravel plugin is enabled by running vendor/bin/psalm-plugin show

Enabled psalm/plugin-laravel
